# Writing gpg decrypted file to a specified outfile

Tags: gnupg

I attempted to decrypt an encrypted gpg file using:

```
gpg -d <encrypted file> --output <outfile>
```

and just get a message:
usage: gpg [options] --decrypt [filename]

In contrast, if I use

```
gpg -d <encrypted file>
```

the file is decrypted, but it's written to a default file and displayed to the terminal screen. The former isn't a big issue, but the latter (display in terminal screen while decrypting) is a real nuisance. What, if anything, can be done about it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try `gpg --output <outfile> -d <encrypted file>`

Comment: this one does not written in the documentation. glad I found this answer.

Comment: Not the greatest documentation, but technically it is documented because the syntax is `gpg [options] command [args]`. `-d` is listed under `Commands`, and `-o` is listed under Options. So that's why `-o` needs to be before `-d`. Not the best UX though.

Answer (score 2):

The "-d" is unnecessary, this is fine:

```
gpg -o plaintext.txt ciphertext.asc
```

As for printing the decypted data to stdout, that usually only happens when the sender uses the old "for-your-eyes-only" flag.  To determine exactly what is happening there, though, I'd need more detail on the version of GPG in use and possibly some information on the ciphertext.